# Find details of device based on dns name using ip command

Tags: linux, dns, ip, arp

When I'm retrieving the mac address of a device 
I execute following command

```
$ arp <dnsname> | grep "HWaddress" -A1 | awk '{print $1 "" $3}' |head -2 | tail -1
```

this will probably print

```
<dnsname> <mac address>
```

As I've seen from the manual of arp is that it is deprecated and alternate I have is to use 'ip' command instead of arp .

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to obtain the mac address using ip command?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the MAC address of the device running this code, or of some arbitrary device on the same LAN?

Comment: @Helio my input is dnsname and my required output is mac address. by above command I can do it easily but arp is depricated and i was suggested to use 'ip'. so I need to achieve the same result using 'ip'

Comment: @roaima I will pass the dnsname in the local network and fetch the mac address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arp` is able to take names as input and print names in output.  `ip` uses addresses only.

If you can deal with addresses, then modifying the output is pretty easy.

```
$ ip neigh show to 10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 lladdr dc:fb:02:xx:xx:xx REACHABLE

$ ip neigh show to 10.0.0.1 | awk '{print $1 " " $5}'
10.0.0.1 dc:fb:02:xx:xx:xx
```

I just noticed that your title specifically asks about DNS names.  If that's the requirement, then you'll want to translate the name in your script.

```
$ ip neigh show to `getent hosts <dnsname> | awk '{print $1}'` | awk '{print $1 " " $5}'
$ 10.0.0.1 dc:fb:02:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: You'll be better using `$( ... )` instead of backticks, i.e. `ip neigh show to $(getent hosts <dnsname> | awk '{print $1}') | awk '{print $1 " " $5}'`